# Check for existance of directory always fails in Bash Script

Tags: bash, directory, getopt

I have a problem that has been bugging me for a few hours now. I have created a parameter `--file-dir` using getopt, which assigns a directory for the program to use. Following the parameter, the user has the choice to choose whatever directory they please. To keep the program stable, I check to see whether that directory even exists. The following code is what I have currently and it always returns "Directory does not exist. Terminating." even when I search for my `/home` directory.

`-a|--file-dir) FILE_DIR=$2 ; 
    if [ ! -d "$FILE_DIR" ]; then
        echo "Directory does not exist. Terminating." ;
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "Directory exists." ;
    fi ;
    shift;;`

Any input is much appreciated. The getopt's work fine with echo tests and such but fail when checking for directories.

Comment: Try changing the shebang (very first line) of your script and appending a space followed by `-xv` and re-running it to see the lines of script as they get executed. New first line will look something like `#!/bin/bash -xv`

Comment: Your question isn't focused properly. It seems your problem is about checking existence of a directory but you mention getopt and you're showing a snippet of a case statement. I was expecting: look, I do `ls` here and look `banana` is a directory, but look when I do `[ -d banana ]` it doesn't work. Your question is, in this respect, no well posed. It's impossible for us to determine where your problem is, without doing impossibly wild guesses—someone might be _lucky_ and prove me wrong, though, but I stand my point: your question isn't well focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to check if you're really having the right argument for it:

```
-a|--file-dir) FILE_DIR=$2 ; 
    if [ ! -d "$FILE_DIR" ]; then
        echo "Directory \"$FILE_DIR\" does not exist. Terminating." ;
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "Directory exists." ;
    fi ;
    shift;;
```

If not certainly the problem is not in the checker but somewhere in your argument-parsing loop.

Comment: I had an argument "echo $FILE_DIR" right before the if statement to make sure. I just took it out to make the code smaller on the website. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the same behavior: checking for a directory in the command line worked as expected, but always failed when done in a script.

I was running this script under git bash for Windows:

```
while read -r i; do
    [ ! -d "$i" ] && echo "No $i"
done < "$1"
```

Windows' line endings (`\r\n`) can cause issues when splitting lines. Each test actually checks for `directory\r` instead of `directory`. Therefore, I needed to run the `read` command with the correct delimiter:

```
while IFS=$'\r\n' read -r i; do
```

It is possible that OP also had a similar issue, where non-printable characters got in the way.